# Javascript: document.createElement('div') seems to add margin

Tags: javascript, margin, createelement

so I was just messing around with some Javascript for learning purposes and noticed a weird behavior.

I created buttons that, on click, create a duplicate of themselves. The first newly created button has a left margin that I cannot find an explanation for. Does anyone know the reason for that and how to remove that unwanted spacing?

```js
var makeNewBtn = function() {
  var newBtn = document.createElement('button');
  newBtn.className = 'btn';
  newBtn.textContent = 'Click Me';
  newBtn.onclick = makeNewBtn;
  document.getElementById('buttons').appendChild(newBtn);
};

document.getElementsByClassName('btn')[0].onclick = makeNewBtn;
```

```css
body {
  padding: 25px;
}

.btn {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: beige;
  font: 18px Arial;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
  outline: none;    
}
```

```html
<div id="buttons">
  <button class="btn">Click Me</button>
</div>
```

[result here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TsuMp.png)

Comment: Does inspect element on the created div point to where the margin is coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues here:

**You have a space after the first button in the HTML**

Remove the spaces between the `<div>` and the `<button>`.

```
<div id="buttons"><button class="btn">Click Me</button></div>
```

Here's a great article about the many ways to "fight" against this space: https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

**You didn't set margin/padding for the button styles**

If not explicitly set, the browser may use a margin/padding, or inherit these from another style.

```
.btn {
    padding: 0;
}
```

Here is a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1cg6uvdh/ I changed the background color to red so that the gaps are more visible.

Comment: Ahhh, of course! Thanks a lot. The link about "fighting" the spaces was especially useful to me.